# Intuitive calculation of logarithms

Tags: calculus

So I was going through a rate of growth question. The question itself was pretty simple (The annual exponential growth rate of the population that increases by 20% in 10 years).

But the examination doesn't really allow log tables. The answers were multiple choice (with options like 2%, more than 2%, less than 2%, none of the above).

I don't know how to calculate this w/o log table. Is there a way to gain an approximation of the answer? Since the options aren't exact, I think they expect us to guess the answer sortof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple interest at 2% would give 20% growth in 10 years.  Compound interest at 2% would give MORE than 20% growth in 10 years, since you would be earning interest on the interest.  Hence if you only got 20% growth in 10 years, the compound interest must be LESS than 2%.